# LDAP SSL access

Tags: ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate

I have an application which can access a LDAP server with non-SSL connection. Now, the LDAP server has been configured to support only SSL.
So, now what are the new components or changes in the existing components which I have to do.

Comment: Provide more information: what clients?

Answer (score 0):

If your application really doesn't support SSL (btw it would've made things easier if you'd told us what program you're trying to use), you can try an SSL wrapper, such as [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) that can be configured to connect to the SSL-protected LDAP service whenever your program connects to the "entrance" of the tunnel. This way, your program doesn't have to support SSL, but your connection to the LDAP server is still secured by SSL (if the SSL wrapper runs on the same host as your program).

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to change ldap: to ldaps: in the client.